# How to install the Budgie desktop environment on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, desktop-environments, budgie

Is there any way install budgie desktop environment on Ubuntu and is  it safe to install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Budgie desktop can be installed with a PPA since a few days. It is still a beta so expect bugs and non-functional features.

> [Budgie](https://evolve-os.com/budgie/) is the flagship desktop of the Evolve OS Linux Distribution, and is an Evolve OS project. Designed with the modern user in mind, it focuses on simplicity and elegance. A huge advantage for the Budgie desktop is that it is not a fork of another project, but rather one written from scratch with integration in mind.
>
> The Budgie Desktop tightly integrates with the GNOME stack, employing underlying technologies to offer an alternative desktop experience. In the spirit of open source, the project is compatible with and available for other Linux distributions.
>
> Also note that Budgie can now emulate the look and feel of the GNOME 2 desktop, optionally, via a setting in the panel preferences. An example of this is shown in a screenshot further down.

---

> **[Features in the 0.8 release](https://evolve-os.com/2014/11/16/courageous-budgie-v8-released/)**

```
IconTasklist: Add pinning support
IconTasklist: Use .desktop files for quicklists
IconTasklist: Use .desktop files for icon resolution
IconTasklist: Support “attention” hint (blue blink)
Panel: Support dark theme (used by default)
Add Menubar applet
Panel: Initial autohide support (manual, not automatic)
Panel: Support shadow onall screen edges
Panel: Dynamic support for gnome panel theming
RunDialog: Complete visual refresh (bootiful)
BudgieMenu: Add compact mode, use by default
BudgieMenu: Sort items by usage
BudgieMenu: Remove old power option
Editor: Add all menu options to UI
Support from GNOME 3.10 up to 3.16 (unreleased, git)
wm: Kill workspace animation (resolve after v8)
wm: Better animations for changing of wallpapers
```

---

> **[Installation](https://launchpad.net/%7Eevolve-os/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:evolve-os/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop
```

---

> **Important information**

- Budgie released version 0.8 so it is still in development and a beta.
- No nnative network management; can be fixed by using Ubuntu's applet.
- Budgie is intended for the Evolve OS so even with this PPA it might be buggy.
- GNOME themes work better than the native Ubuntu themes.
- Ubuntu’s overlay scrollbars are not working.
- If you want to read more visit the [Evolve OS website](https://evolve-os.com/2014/11/16/courageous-budgie-v8-released/).

Answer (score 4):

You can build budgie desktop from source yourself

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gnome-common gobject-introspection libglib2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libmutter-dev libwnck-3-dev libupower-glib-dev libgnome-menu-3-dev libc6-dev
git clone https://github.com/evolve-os/budgie-desktop.git
cd budgie-desktop
./autogen.sh
make 
sudo make install
```

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04, you can try [my unofficial budgie desktop PPA](https://launchpad.net/~sukso96100/+archive/budgie-desktop)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sukso96100/budgie-desktop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop
```

(Update-2014.11.09)You can now use [Budgie Desktop Offcial PPA](https://launchpad.net/~evolve-os/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:evolve-os/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop
```

Comment: The PPA is really useful to test the desktop. Unfortunately, it contains bugs that makes is unusable. Anyway, awesome work... I think it will be a great project.

Comment: @sukso Is there any PPA for Ubuntu 15.10 or should i build it for myself from the sources?

Comment: @kisanme - http://askubuntu.com/a/735961/14356

Answer (score 4):

### 16.04

The budgie-remix team maintain a PPA containing the latest budgie-desktop for 16.04 (and 16.10) users.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:budgie-remix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop
```

Logout and login to the budgie-desktop

[image]

budgie-desktop needs a compatible theme - at the time of writing we recommend either arc-theme, adapta or paper-gtk themes. moka icon-set and arc-theme are available in the PPA.

Bug reports go to the [project issues page](https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop)

[source](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2016/02/15/installing-budgie-desktop-via-ppa/) for this is my blog

### 16.10

v10.2.7 of budgie-desktop is available from the universe repository for 16.10 users.

```
sudo apt install budgie-desktop
```

The latest available version of the desktop is available in the budgie-remix PPA (same instructions at 16.04 above)